# How can I share my MSO questions on Facebook?

Tags: support, meta, facebook, twitter

How can I share my MSO questions on Twitter or my Facebook wall?

I can share my SO questions. Why can't I do the same for Meta posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (now) - just click the "share" link below your question, and then click the little Facebook icon:

[image: the share UI]